# MongoDB Community is not yet available for Ubuntu 22.04, any workarounds?

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu-22.04

Per MongoDB, platform support for Ubuntu 22.04 x86 & ARM is currently in backlog (2 issues tracked [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-62301) and [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-62301))

Looking for a workaround so that I can leverage a local database environment for development purposes until these tickets are closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MongoDB via Docker container and put the container's port back-to-back w/ localhost's 27017. Make sure you persist docker container data to a specified directory

Original solution recommended by someone else on MongoDB Forum
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/installing-mongodb-over-ubuntu-22-04/159931/11

Use Docker Engine, Digital Ocean has a great [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-22-04#step-7-committing-changes-in-a-container-to-a-docker-image)
create a docker container by running the following

`$ docker run --name mongodb -d -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=joe -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=joes_pw -v YOUR_LOCAL_DIR:/data/db mongo`

`$ docker update --restart unless-stopped mongodb`